# Jquery - How can I check if all of the checkboxes are unchecked?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox, smarty

For some reason my code doesn't work?! I need to check checkboxes, if all are "unchecked", then enable hidden field and send value to db, so I can identify that checkboxes were unchecked.

**Question 1:** Why isn't my jquery code working?

**Question 2:** I need to record checked or unchecked values to DB. My plan is to check if none selected in php. Is this a good practice?

**HTML**

```
<tr class="more_info">
        <th valign="top">Other options:</th>
        {foreach from=$HTML_cOPTIONS key=dbname item=optname}
            {if ! empty($CARINFO[car].{$dbname})}
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="forced_checkbox" name="c_options[]" value="{$dbname}" checked/> {$optname} </br></td>
            {else}
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="forced_checkbox" name="c_options[]" value="{$dbname}"/> {$optname} </br></td>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
        <input type="hidden" id="forceSendCheckBox" name="c_options[]" value="nocheckboxes"/>
        <input type="button" value="Check" id="check" />
    </tr>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#check').bind('click',function()
{
    if ($('#forced_checkbox').filter(':not(:checked)').length == 0) {
        console.log('at least one checked');
        $("#forceSendCheckBox").prop('disabled',true);//do not send this field to DB
    } else {
        console.log('nothing checked');
        $("#forceSendCheckBox").prop('disabled',false);//send empty checkboxes
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle, it still seems to be broken. :-/

http://jsfiddle.net/L5J96/

Comment: Why does your title say you need to check if all are checked, but your description says you need to ask if all are unchecked?

Comment: You have no element `id="check"`.

Comment: @crazy train, it was a typo. You have over 2000 rep, and couldn't edit a typo?! It took you longer to comment.

Comment: @Timur: I didn't know which one you wanted. Most people would offer a thank you for pointing out the contradiction. Ultimately, your question is your responsibility, not mine.

Comment: ...and just so you're aware, this code: `.filter(':not(:checked)').length == 0` is coupled with this message: `console.log('at least one checked')`, which seems odd.  If there are `0` non-checked boxes, then one would state that `"all are checked"`, instead of `"at least one checked"`. So if you want to see if all are "unchecked", then you should do `.filter(":checked").length == 0`. Or if you wanted to know if at least one is checked, then: `.filter(":checked").length`

Comment: @crazy train +1 for explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. Use a class instead.

In your fiddle you had several problems. First, you forgot to select the jQuery framework from the menu, so none of the jQuery code worked. Second, you changed the filter from `not(:checked)` to `(:checked)`, but didn't change `== 0` to `> 0`. Third, without the `not`, you shouldn't have parentheses around the filter selector. Fourth, you tried to display the message in an input field using `.text()`, but the correct method is `.val()`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
$('#check').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.forced_checkbox').filter(':checked').length > 0) {
        $('#forceSendCheckBox').val('at least one checked');
    } else {
        $('#forceSendCheckBox').val('nothing checked');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/L5J96/5/)

Comment: I tried, that didn't seem to help, i've also attached fiddle to the post

Comment: I've fixed all the problems in your fiddle.

Comment: Actually, changed my answer and chose yours. I attached event to checkboxes and it works like a charm. I guess the main piece of information i was missing was > sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar mentioned, the IDs must be unique.

Next, use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` - similar syntax, so easy to do. (.bind is deprecated)

However, to answer your question, you can quickly discover which checkboxes were not checked by selecting all unchecked checkboxes and iterating through them.

If you need to create a list of which checkboxes were unchecked, then you need something unique about each one (if every man in the room is named 'Bob', then making a useful list of all the men with brown hair will be difficult). Use the ID attr for that, as in the jsFiddle example at bottom.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BZxgP/)

[Here is an expanded jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BZxgP/2/) that demonstrates how to save the list of unchecked checkboxes into a hidden field, as requested in your post.

---

With respect to your jsFiddle, the following things needed adjusting:

[See revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5J96/1/)

1. Use of the `.on()` syntax.  Use `.on(document)` or `.on(body)` instead:

   `$('document').on('action', '#elementID', function() { //Do stuff here });`
2. In order to interate through the collection of unchecked objects, you should use jQuery's `.each()` method.

   `$('.forced_checkbox').filter(':not(:checked)').each(function() { //Do stuff });`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed from bind() to on() and replaced IDs with class, it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle. [Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/L5J96/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/L5J96/1/). I trust it is what you want. Note that you can use unique ID attributes if you wish to keep track of **which** checkboxes remain unchecked.

Comment: thanks, +1 for iteration method. That's the one i finally went with.